# Analytics API: Getting Quota Limit Error on just 10000 out of the 50000 daily queries

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using a [WordPress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-post-pageviews/) on my website to show the actual views on each post, pulling the number from Google Analytics. The plugin uses the Analytics API.

At first, it worked great. However, a few hours in, I run into an error that I have exceeded the daily request limit. The error didn't go away until the quota reset at midnight pacific time.

The thing is, I checked my quotas at the console, and I had made barely more than 10,000, nowhere near the 50,000 limit.

[Quota](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COH8N.png)

I was thinking of requesting to increase the quota, but since I am nowhere near the 50,000, this does not seem to be a solution. Let alone that to request an increase I should have been at about 80% of the current quota.

To avoid the problem, I can have the plugin check the post views every four hours, instead of every hour, through the plugin's settings. But, since I am supposed to have 50000 daily queries, I would prefer to update the views on an hourly basis.

I understand that the current quota at the Google Developer console is a estimate it is not 100% accurate. But could it be so much off, showing 10k when the real number is 50k?

Should I ask for an extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most likely hitting the profile quota limit, which cannot be increased.

More information [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas#additional_quota)

> The 10,000 requests per view (profile) per day or the 10 concurrent requests per view (profile) cannot be increased.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be it.